# Google maps class not getting imported in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to integrate google maps api in my flutter app.

I have used 3 libraries: google_map, dio and flutter_polyline_points from pub.dev

My error is that even after doing "pubspec run", the `GoogleMap()` class is not getting recognized.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:travel/widgets/home_page_sidebar.dart';

class MapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "MapsScreen";
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MapsScreenState();
  }
}

class MapsScreenState extends State<MapsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Travel"
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: HomePageSideBar(),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap()
    );
  }

}
```

I am getting red line under `GoogleMap()` in android studio. I have tried restarting the app but it doesn't work.

Why is the class not getting recognized?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the docs for the google_maps lib shows it's probably named [`GMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps/latest/google_maps/GMap-class.html), not `GoogleMap`.

Here's the example from their [pub.dev docs page](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps):

```dart
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
  final mapOptions = MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  GMap(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo esta lib
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

GoogleMap(
mapType: MapType.hybrid,
initialCameraPosition: initialPosition,
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
_controller.complete(controller);
},
),